# How to dynamically create buttons names and detect which button is pressed in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

This is an experiment int PHP that I'm currently working on. It'll be part of a bigger file.
The idea is, the program will generate a set of submit buttons in a form and a unique name will be assigned to each button in this convention: **btn**[*the order of button*]

The page will then poll to find if any button was pressed using isset(). Here's what I've got so far.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Dynamic Naming</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="testDynamicNaming.php" method="POST">
        <?php
            $row = 9;

            for($i = 0; $i < $row; $i++) {
                $name = 'btn['.$i.']';

                ?>
                    <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/>
                <?php

                echo "<br>";
            }
        ?>
    </form>

    <?php
        extract($_REQUEST);

        for($i = 0; $i < $row; $i++) {
            $name = 'btn['.$i.']';

            if(isset($_POST[$name])) {
                echo "<br><br>".$name.' is pressed.';
            }

            // OR

            if(isset($$name)) {
                echo "<br><br>".$name.' is pressed.';
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I managed to set the name and values of the button as I wanted but the page couldn't detect the button that was pressed. What am I missing here, or is there any other way that I could accomplish the same task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use

```
if(isset($_POST['btn'][$i])) {
            echo "<br><br>".$_POST['btn'][$i].' is pressed.';
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($_POST['btn'])){
  foreach($_POST['btn'] as $key => $value){
    echo "Button {$key}:{$value} pressed";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This also work. It's just that I didn't really understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use javascript?

easy e.g.

```
     <input type="submit" name="<?php echo $name; ?>" onclick="document.getElementById('<?php echo $name; ?>_pressed').value='true';" value="1"/>
     <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $name; ?>_pressed" name="x1_pressed" value="false"> 

if(isset($_POST[$name]) == "true") {
```

Comment: I didn't learn much about javascript, so I didn't really understand or know how to use it. But thanks anyway. :)

Comment: This it very easy javascript.... Explain: document.getElementById('NAME-BY-ID-TAG').value = "something" - this set value of some form element. So in this I change "false" to "true" on hidden element. After in PHP you check only elements with suffix e.g. "pressed". .... (sorry for my bad english :))

Comment: I've tried it. It works. :)
I'll probably going to understand better next semester when I take the javascript course.

Comment: :-) This is basic javascript really. If you think that is true solution, please mark it is as answer:).